# Can you call for a medic? How?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2, keyboard

I asked in game about how to call a medic and someone said that you press <kbd>Q</kbd>.  But I couldn't get it to work, so maybe this person was pulling my chain.

How do you call for a medic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On PS3, you have to target a medic of your team (i.e. look at him with your crosshairs) and press <kbd>Select</kbd>.

You're on PC and <kbd>Q</kbd> is the right key, so I'm guessing the problem is you didn't target a friendly medic with your crosshair first. They have to be close enough. If it works, you'll hear your guy screaming out for help.

Comment: Yes, it is Q on PC.

Comment: expanding: if you do this while looking at an assault class, it'll ask for ammo; for engineers it'll ask for repairs.

Comment: I find it a bit idiotic to first look for a medic before you can cry out for help. I prefer bf42 mechanism: F2, F1 MEDIC!

Answer (score -1):

The answer (if you are on pc) is actually ***E*** to call for medic.So I think he *WAS* pulling your leg. :\

Comment: This question is about Bad Company 2, not Team Fortress 2.